# Running a server application process along with "logger"

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, openwrt

I received an application code that can be run on Linux kernel 4.4.60 as below cmd - per their app note :-

```
/usr/sbin/server_application | logger -t tag &
```

If I run the server_application with just "`server_application &`" (in the background), then the socket which the process attempts to create fails the initiation. And obviously the client_application (run separately of course) times out.

From my info, the **linux logger utilities only make entries in the system log.**

*Q. -- What is it the application might need which requires the application to log the tag entries in the syslog?*

I am trying to reverse engineer as to why it needs logger specifically.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: Yeah no direct relation, removed C tag.

Comment: So, does this have anything to do with programming?  It sounds like you should be asking on SuperUser or something like that.

Comment: I thought in a way, it does. I was trying to reverse engg an application which appears to use logger piped output as input for itself to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the `server_application` in background the process might not have standard output *at all* opened to anything and any writes to `stdout` will fail. If you create a pipeline piping the standard output to a program then the `server_application` will have different characteristics for its `stdout`.

You could also try to figure out the difference by running these two with `strace`, for example:

```
strace -o /tmp/syscall.log /usr/sbin/server_application &
strace -o /tmp/syscall.log /usr/sbin/server_application | logger -t tag &
```

and by reading the `/tmp/syscall.log` looking for failed system calls near the end of the run for the former and then comparing them with the calls from the latter.

Comment: Thanks. 1. To summarize, here the application program 'server_application' would take the 'tag' appearing on the stdout as the input to the app itself and run accordingly. As such I can use any other utility to dump the tag lines on stdout, as I don't have logger in my kernel. tee does not seem to serve that purpose as it does not take the tag as input but can redirect the whole stream of text. Can you please let me know if you are aware of any alternatives to logger? 2. My kernel does not have strace; is there any other way you are aware of?